# Problema al expandir clave en aes en c

Tags: c, criptografía

Mi problema es al crear las subclaves, cuando imprimo las subclaves me da unas variables como esta: 0xfffffff, y no se cual es el error ya que llevo mucho tiempo rompiendome la cabeza tratando de encontrar el error estoy siguiendo este PDF para hacer el codigo. [PDF Cifrado Aes 128](http://sedici.unlp.edu.ar/bitstream/handle/10915/4210/Documento_completo.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

La clave es: 0x49 0x6d 0x54 0x68 0x65 0x4f 0x6e 0x65 0x57 0x68 0x6f 0x4b 0x6e 0x6f 0x63 0x6b

Salida: [image: Salida del programa]

Perdonen si la pregunta es muy larga pero no me puedo explicar mejor, gracias de antemano.

```
void ExpandirClave( char Clave[4][4], char ClaveExpandida[4][44] ){ 

char ClaveCopia[4];
char ClaveAux ; 

printf("\n");
printf("\t  [>>] Expandiendo Clave... \n");

for( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ ){ /* Se copia la Clave en la clave expandida. */
    for( int j=0 ; j<4 ; j++ ){
        ClaveExpandida[j][i] = Clave[j][i];
    }
}

for( int i=4 ; i<44 ; i++ ){
    for( int j=0 ; j<4 ; j++ ){
        ClaveCopia[j] = ClaveExpandida[j][i-1];     
    }
    if( i%4 == 0 ){

        ClaveAux = ClaveCopia[0];       // Se hace el rotword de un bit 
        ClaveCopia[0] = ClaveCopia[1];
        ClaveCopia[1] = ClaveCopia[2];
        ClaveCopia[2] = ClaveCopia[3];
        ClaveCopia[3] = ClaveAux;

        for( int j=0 ; j<4 ; j++ ){     // Se hace la SubBytes 
            ClaveCopia[j] = S_Box(ClaveCopia[j]);
        }

        ClaveCopia[0] = ClaveCopia[0] ^ RCON[i/4];
    }
    for( int j=0 ; j<4 ; j++ ){
        ClaveExpandida[j][i] = ClaveExpandida[j][i-4] ^ ClaveCopia[j];
    } 
}
printf("\t  [>>] Clave expandida. \n");
```

Imprimo la clave expandida con este codigo

```
for( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ ){
    for( int j=0 ; j<44 ; j++ ){
        printf("0x%2x ", ClaveExpandida[i][j] );
    }
}
```

La verdad quiero saber si la salida de mi programa esta bien o no y si es que no que deberia cambiar.

Comment: Buenas. Deberías A) mostrar el código con el que imprimes los valores y B) explicar que resultado esperas obtener.

Comment: @SJuan76 agrague los puntos que me dijiste a la pregunta , el codigo para imprimir y los resultados esperados.